# Bit-wise with Z3?

Tags: z3

I write the following Z3 python code

```
x, y = Ints('x y')
F = (x == y & 16)      # x has the value of (y & 16)
print F
```

But I get bellow error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'instance' and 'int'
```

How to do bitwise arithmetic (& in this case) in Z3 equation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`x` and `y` should be bit-vectors:

```
x, y = BitVecs('x y', 32)
F = (x == y & 16)      # x has the value of (y & 16)
print F
```

See Bitvectors section under http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/guide